# You see me everywhere

Tags: riddle, word

You see me everywhere.

Many times you don't even think about me but I'm still there.

Sometimes I can be present in relationships, both physical and non-physical.

Lately, I've become very important.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably

> **distance**

You see me everywhere.

> Check

Many times you don't even think about me but I'm still there.

> Check

Sometimes I can be present in relationships, both physical and non-physical.

> You can maintain distance physically and limiting verbal interactions could also refer to keeping a distance

Lately, I've become very important.

> Could refer to social *distancing*

Comment: Yes correct, this is the intended answer!

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> health

but after a secong thought I think you rather mean

> safety.

Comment: No, not the intended answer, neither of them.